# Enable VMX/SVM on Google Kubernetes Engine Cluster

Tags: android, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, emulation, google-kubernetes-engine

I have `GKE` cluster (Master version: 1.14.10-gke.24).

I'm trying to run the following container (Android-Emulator):
https://github.com/budtmo/docker-android .

*I just create yaml deployment file for this.

After I running my deploy and try to run new android emulator inside the pod using:

```
emulator @samsung_galaxy_s8_8.0
```

I got the following error:

> emulator: ERROR: x86 emulation currently requires hardware acceleration!
>
> Please ensure KVM is properly installed and usable.
>
> CPU acceleration status: KVM requires a CPU that supports vmx or svm
>
> More info on configuring VM acceleration on Linux:
>   https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-acceleration#vm-linux
>
> General information on acceleration: https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-acceleration.

How can I solve it? Should I enable VMX on cluster, If so, how can I do it?

Comment: Itsounds like you have to have Nested Virtualization here. Have you been checking https://b.corp.google.com/issues/110507927 ? 
 This doc https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/enable-nested-virtualization-vm-instances describes how-to on GCP (though it's not GKE)

Comment: @Nick - I saw this, I looking for same solution on GKE

Answer (score 1):

Currently nested virtualization is available only on GCE as per [this docs](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/enable-nested-virtualization-vm-instances).

There is already a [question](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/gce-discussion/kXlnM2m60hY) regarding supporting of `Nested Virtualization` on `GKE`. I'd say it's not introduced yet, thats why you cannot find proper documentation about GKE and `nested virtualization`.

So far I can see only one workaround:

> As a workaround, I've been doing what this user was doing which is to clone the existing GKE node image and add the license, and copy-and-edit the instance group's template to the image:
>
> https://groups.google.com/d/msg/kubernetes-users/Lq0ttadDOYI/1y1RVQMCBgAJ
>
> Obviously it's not 100% supported but I still get a lot of the GKE benefits AND nested virtualization.

Hope that helps.